# OP5t - Decrypt an encrypted data folder from a second user after reset

Tags: factory-reset, oneplus-5t

Basically what happened was that the camera on my phone decided to not work so I did the factory reset without wiping data (in the OOS settings) but forgot to do a backup on my second user. Is there a way to decrypt this? If so, how does one do that? I had some important *things* on that user.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do a factory reset encryption PIN is also reset and you cannot decrypt  anything be it on primary or secondary user by that PIN

It's practically impossible to recover data

Comment: I had feared this. Thanks for clarification, anyway :/